# No placeholders of database data showing up in the textboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I try to get the data from my database to the textboxes of the current logged in user to change their profile data but the

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM klant where Email = ?";
```

Doesnt seem to work. But when I use `$sql = "SELECT * FROM klant`
it works but it gets the first user from the database instead of the current logged in user. I don't get any error messages.

Anyway I can make it work?

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION["ID"])&&($_SESSION["STATUS"]!="ACTIEF")){
    echo "<script> alert('U heeft geen toegang tot deze pagina.');
    location.href='../index.php'</script>";
}
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM klant where Email = ?";
    $stmt = $verbinding->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array( $_SESSION["E-MAIL"] ));
    $resultaat = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOEception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>

<div class="content">
    <form method="POST" action="index.php?page=profiel_update">
        <p id="page_titel">Profiel editen</p>
        <label for="voornaam">Voornaam</label>
        <input type="text" required name="voornaam" value="<?php echo $resultaat['Voornaam']; ?>" />
        <label for="achternaam">Achternaam</label>
        <input type="text" required name="achternaam" value="<?php echo $resultaat['Achternaam']; ?>" />
        <label for="straat">Voornaam</label>
        <input type="text" required name="straat" value="<?php echo $resultaat['Straat']; ?>" />
        <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" required name="postcode" value="<?php echo $resultaat['Postcode']; ?>" />
        <label for="woonplaats">Woonplaats</label>
        <input type="text" required name="woonplaats" value="<?php echo $resultaat['Woonplaats']; ?>" />
        <label for="e-mail">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" required name="e-mail" value="<?php echo $resultaat['Email']; ?>" />
        <br/>
        <div class="icon_container">
            <input type="submit" class="icon" id="submit" name="submit" value="&rarr;" />
        </div>
        <a href="index.php?page=webshop">Terug</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You never start your session

Comment: Did you forget to start your session?  `session_start()`

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION["ID"])&&($_SESSION["STATUS"]!="ACTIEF")){` also that doesn't make much sense - if the session is not set, there is no value to check against - you probably want `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: Session has already been started

Comment: In that particular script? At the top of the page, what is `var_dump($_SESSION);`?

Comment: Yes in index.php <?php
session_start();
include_once("DBconfig.php");
include_once("header.html");
if(isset($_GET["page"])){
    $page = $_GET["page"];
} else{
    $page = "inloggen";
}
if ($page) {
    include("pages/" . $page . ".php");
}


?>

Comment: @Qirel They're two different session variables: `ID` versus `STATUS` But you're probably still correct about `||`

Comment: Are you sure `$_SESSION['E-MAIL']` is correctly filled in?

Comment: I use that code at every page, it works like its supposed to do @barmar

Comment: @Barmar Whops, you're absolutely right - different indexes entirely, must've missed that..

Comment: @RobinR Probably because the two session variables are always consistent with each other, so you never run into the case where it makes a difference.

Comment: The way you've written the code looks fine, so the only possible problem is that `$_SESSION['E-MAIL']` doesn't contain the correct value. Add `var_dump($_SESSION['E-MAIL']);`.

Comment: @barmar possible, I tried to echo the session but didn't received anything but from session ID, I did got something

Comment: when you inspect the contents of `$_SESSION` (see comments by Barmar), look out for `E-MAIL` vs `E_MAIL` vs `EMAIL`; we've all been bitten by that sort of thing before

Comment: *"but didn't received anything but from session ID, I did got something"* : do you mean that `ID` is the only member of `$_SESSION`?  if so, are you sure you are populating the rest of `$_SESSION`, say, when the user logs in?  and are you sure the your user sessions are staying intact from page-load to page-load?

Comment: So the problem has nothing to do with mysql, you have a problem with the way you're setting session variables.